# FadeIn fadeOut depending upon the previous option value in select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've 10 select tags like

```
<div class="ques"><select><option></option><option></option></select></div>
<div class="ques"><select><option></option><option></option></select></div>
<div class="ques"><select><option></option><option></option></select></div>
 <div class="ques"><select><option></option><option></option></select></div>
<div class="ques"><select><option></option><option></option></select></div>
 <div class="ques"><select><option></option><option></option></select></div>
.
.
<div class="ques"><select><option></option><option></option></select></div>
```

Now what I want is 
Very first of them should be visible by default. When user select any value from that `select tag` the next select tag now should be visible. And so so for the next tags.
And If user deselects value of a tag, all of the next tags should fade out.

What I've tried is something like

```
 <script>
$(".ques").click(function(){
 var x = $(this).find('select').attr('id')

 if(x ==1)
{
//Here I check for the selected value
//fadeIn the next select tag
}
if(x ==2)
{
//fadeIn the next select tag
}
//And so ON
});
</script>
```

I am just looking for a better and efficient solution.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is this homework or something, I answered a very similar question yesterday

Comment: Nah it's not. 
I am just trying to add it in my web

Comment: Have a look at my answer in the duplicate question - you should be able to use the same sort of thing but instead of disabling it, just fade out / in as required

Comment: Yeah sure. Thanks for the feedback though :)

Comment: Quick adjustment: https://jsfiddle.net/3n3089v5/